# Animated imageview stop animation

Tags: ios, animation, imageview, gif, uianimation

I am using imageview animation property to display multiple picture in animation. When user come back to Imageview screen using UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight, imageview stop animating. And when click on any of button imageview starts animating again.

Answer (score 0):

...And I guess that's not what you want and you want help fixing it?

It's a good idea to ask a specific question. You should also provide the code in question. In this case the code that creates the UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animation would be helpful, as well as the code that starts the UIView animation, and a diagram of the view hierarchy that shows how the view you're flipping relates to the image view that is doing frame animation.

How about you add a completion block to your UIView animateWithDuration: call that uses UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight and have it start the image view animating again.